# Environment variable not getting set in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have  added following code in My makefile

```
RHELC="0"
UBUNTUC="0"
SUSEC="0"
RHELC=$(shell cat /etc/*-release | grep rhel -c)
UBUNTUC=$(shell cat /etc/*-release | grep ubuntu -c)
SUSEC=$(shell cat /etc/*-release | grep suse -c)

ifneq "${RHELC}" "0"
   OS_DIST="RHEL"
endif
ifneq "${UBUNTUC}" "0"
   OS_DIST="UBUNTU"
endif
ifneq "${SUSEC}" "0"
   OS_DIST="SUSE"
endif
```

But OS_DIST is not getting set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things wrong here.  Realize that a makefile is not a shell script, and they have different syntax and rules.

First, please be clear about the difference between *environment* variables and *make* variables.  You are setting make variables here, not environment variables.  The value of these variables will be present in your makefile, but not your environment.

Second, make doesn't do anything special with quotes in variables. They are treated the same as any other character.  When you write:

```
RHELC="0"
```

you are setting the make variable `RHELC` to the literal string `"0"`, including the quotes.  You're not setting it to 0.  Similarly, when you write:

```
OS_DIST="RHEL"
```

you are setting the make variable `OS_DIST` to the literal string `"RHEL"`.

As to your question, you haven't explained why you think that the make variables are not being set.  There is nothing in the makefile you've shown us that checks or uses those values, and there's no output you've shown us that describes how they are used.

So, we cannot help you further.

One thing you can do to debug your makefile is use the `$(info ...)` make function to show the values of the variables:

```
$(info RHELC=$(RHELC))
```

for example.